# Provision profile problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

My app's provision profile expired 2 days back, i created a new one and now it gives me the error:

Code Signing Entitlements Do Not Match Provisioning Profile

EveryThing is same,jus the profile name is changed..

Anyone here knws wat's the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen that you have not created your provisioning profile for the same application id.

The easiest is to create a provisioning profile for the app id "*" (in case you are not using special things, like push) - and you can use this provisioning profile for every application of yours. 
Also - you can delete your provisioning profile from the apple developer website and your xcode organizer, and you click on the refresh button in organizer then xcode will talk to the apple dev website and download a new one for you.

Hope this helps, Moszi

Comment: but its written there...

You cannot use special characters as @, &, *, " in your description.
then how can i create this app id??